# What framework should I use for a web app associated with a next.js portfolio site?

Tags: web-apps, javascript, software-development, web-development, react

I'm starting an online business and am trying to figure out what framework to use for my web app (the product). So far I've laid out the portfolio in next.js and am looking to "link" it to the app.

Here's some features I thought were important:

- The user should be able to log on to their account on the portfolio site and stay logged in when going to the app
- The app should be directly linked to the portfolio...similar to something like spotify and it's web player where the user just clicks a button on the portfolio and it takes them to the app.
- Once deployed, the app should run on the same domain as the portfolio (but can run off a subdomain if practical...idk much about web hosting)
- The app will have similar functionality to something like Google Drive: where users can make new files and folders as well as view and edit them.
- The web app is the only product right now but there could potentially be more

And here's some solutions I thought of:

1. Make the portfolio site and web app all in one next.js project...essentially just build the web app off the portfolio I already have. This is the simplest solution, but I see myself running into problems if down the road if I wanted to make multiple products or run the app off a sub domain.
2. Make another next.js project and put the app in there. This would solve the domain and scaling problems, and if I'm making another project for the app I'd prefer to continue using next.js. But, this makes authentication more difficult.
3. Use express.js to make the app. I have a good amount of experience with express and like their simple routing. But, I'd be using two different frameworks, so it might be even harder to implement.

Which solution, if any, should I use? I'm open to new ideas. I'd also appreciate any tips on actually linking the portfolio to the app. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While you are using Next.js, you have probably heard [JAM Stack](https://jamstack.org/). Next.js is a front-end SSR framework based on react. So you can use it for the front end ( ex: landing page, dashboard ). For back-end operations ( CRUD ) you can use express , koa , fastly etc. In case of web app, depending upon your application architecture you can use other technologies like Python or Go-lang to build micro-services keeping the entire front-end in next.js.

Comment: Can I just create the web app as a separate express app?

Comment: @MatthewKline Yes, you can use a separate express app and use it with next.js using apis.